# Getting install_pyuic5 error during PyQt5 install

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I have built source files for installing PyQt5 but when I executed `sudo make install`, after a while, it prompts this error message:

```
sudo make install
.
.
.
install -m 755 -p /home/bora/Desktop/PyQt-gpl-5.4.1/pyuic5 /usr/bin/
strip /usr/bin/pyuic5
strip:/usr/bin/pyuic5: File format not recognized
make: [install_pyuic5] Error 1 (ignored)
```

How can I fix this problem? I am using Qt 5.4.1 and I am sure that I have properly set the path to Qt5's `qmake`. If I didn't, it would gave me an error during compilation of source files. Do I need to install any dependecy for PyQt5 another than SIP?

Answer (score 0):

I incurred in the same problem after following this link:
https://michalcodes4life.wordpress.com/2014/03/16/pyqt5-python-3-3-in-virtualenv-on-ubuntu/, I managed to narrow the errors down to the one you're reporting.

Notice in the link where it mentions to run `configure.py` with the `-verbose`flag:

```
python configure.py -verbose --qmake /path/to/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake --sip-incdir=/usr/include/python3.3m
```

Go through the stacktrace and see if the error you reported is the only one. If that is so then *ignore* it as it's just a "warning" in Python parlance. In your command line enter:

```
import sip
import PyQt5
```

should give no errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an error, so you can safely ignore it (just as `make` did).

The output is coming from the `strip` command, which is mainly used for removing debugging symbols from binaries. However, `/usr/bin/pyuic5` is a shell-script rather than a binary, and so `strip` cannot process that file. As a consequence, it outputs a warning message and returns a non-zero exit status. The `make` process sees this, but has been configured to ignore it, and so there is no fatal error.